# add image to a Toolstripbutton from image

Tags: vb.net

I have a small issue with my taskbar.The main idea is to create my own taskbar. And I would like to get the application icon to the ToolbarButton
I am using this code

```
ToolStrip2.Items.Clear()

    For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        Try
            ImgList.Images.Add(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(proc.MainModule.FileName))
            If proc.MainWindowTitle <> "" Then
                Dim menuitem As New ToolStripButton() With
                {
                .Text = proc.MainWindowTitle,
                .Image = ImgList.Images.Count - 1 **//The Error is here**
                }

                ToolStrip2.Items.Add(menuitem)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Next
```

And I get this error "Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'Image'"
I know what does it mean, but I dont know how to solve the problem.

Thanks for Help

Comment: If you know what it means, surely you can pass an image instead of a number?

Comment: but the image is not there yet until the code not run

Comment: Then don't set `.Image` until you have an image to pass? But it would appear to me that you do have an image, the one you are adding to the list right above the `If`?

Comment: my problem is this "Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'Image'"

Comment: That is because you are passing an integer instead of an image. `ImgList.Images.Count` is the number of images in the list, which is an integer. `ImgList.Images.Count - 1` is therefore also an integer, one less than the number of images in the list. An image with the index of `ImgList.Images.Count - 1` would be `ImgList.Images(ImgList.Images.Count - 1)`, did you mean to pass that?

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
ImgList.Images(ImgList.Images.Count - 1)
```

Remember image of toolstrip  must be image not integer!

Comment: Good copy job, Mike. I think the credit should go to GSerg.

Comment: It's answer Dude!!! for example if some one ask you 1+1=? and you say 1+1=2 so it's obvious  if you ask anybody they will tell you 1+1=2 but it's not copy answer it's only answer.